# Calculate the greater of two values in Rules?

Tags: rules

I'm trying to set up a rule which sets a CCK field to the greater of two other CCK fields, but calculate a value only has +-*. How do I figure out the greater of two values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that you can try this to the 'numeric comparison' rule:

[image]

here is the lines used with cck fields `field_test1` and `field_test2`:

```
 <?php $field1 = $form_state['values']['field_test1'][0]['value']; echo $field1; ?>
 <?php $field1 = $form_state['values']['field_test2'][0]['value']; echo $field2; ?>
```